# Load lazy objects only when needed

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am using **hibernate 4.3**.Now scenario in my app is
I have one **Parent** table it contains foreign key referenced from **Address** table.Address having  **@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)** in **Parent** DTO.Now what i want is

**case 1)** I need to fetch data from parent table when User of type **parent** login but don't want to load address in this case.

**case 2)** When parent goes to edit his/her personal information i need to load **parent** along with **address**

I tried with fallowing code

**Servlet**

```
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(HibernateProxyTypeAdapter.FACTORY);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    int parentID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("parentID"));
    return gson.toJson(api.getParentDetails(parentID));
```

**getParentDetails() Method**

```
public HashMap getParentDetails(int parentID) throws Exception {
        Parent parentDetails;
        responseHashMap = Util.getInitialHashMap();
        try {
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            Query q = session.createQuery("from Parent as p where p.parentId=:parentID");
            q.setParameter("parentID", parentID);
            parentDetails = (Parent) q.uniqueResult();
            //Hibernate.initialize(parentDetails.getAddress());

            responseHashMap.put("responseData", parentDetails);
            responseHashMap.put("responseCount", 0);
            if (parentDetails != null) {
                responseHashMap.put("errorCode", 107);
            } else {
                responseHashMap.put("errorCode", 0);
            }
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw e;
        }
        return responseHashMap;

    }
```

Now You can see the commented line

**//Hibernate.initialize(parentDetails.getAddress());**

When i uncomment this line my code works fine but it fails in  **case 1** for me it loads unnecessary data for me as address of parent which i dont want in this case

When i comment the line

**//Hibernate.initialize(parentDetails.getAddress());**

I am getting error

**org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session**

I know that above error is occurring because hibernate goes for lazy objects but it session is not alive there.

Then how could i achieve **Case 1** (See Above) in my app.

Comment: Pass the user to the method so you can check its properties and invoke initialize when you need to?

Comment: @Gimby how can you explain with more detail